# How to parse Dynamic changes in json value. Dictionary with 2 nested dic & then array and then dic again

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsarray, nsdictionary

Dictionary with two nested dictionary and then array and then dictionary again how can i write code generally for objective c ,iOS 8;

```
{
  "brands": {
    "Clinique": {
      "Foundation": {
        "Even Better Makeup SPF 15": {
          "productName": "Even Better Makeup SPF 15",
          "colors": [
            {
              "id": "30816",
              "client_id": "1422956000sjdaC",
              "product_id": "190",
              "shade_name": "Alabaster",
              "shade_code": "#F0C9AE",
              "color_id": null,
              "image_url": "",
              "price": "",
              "offer": "",
              "created_by": "1422956000sjdaC",
              "created_date": "2015-03-06",
              "sku_id": "",
              "product_web_url": "",
              "brand_id": "Clinique",
              "product_name": "Even Better Makeup SPF 15",
              "makeup_type": "Foundation",
              "color_family": "cool"
            },
```

Comment: What's mean "Dynamic changes in json value" ?

Comment: I can see few curly braces are missing. Please provide full 'Json response' code.

Comment: if backend data(json data) can be change frequently .@HuyNghia

Comment: missing three braces in the end . @UmangBista

Comment: How are you fetching data, using _AFNetworking_ or something else?

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, your JSON response is sending Product details, so the

```
"brands": {
    "Clinique": {
      "Foundation": {
```

will remain same always, and the response below it will change according to products.

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

NSDictionary *productsDict = [[jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"brands"] objectForKey:@"Clinique"] objectForKey:@"Foundation"];

NSArray *keys=[productsDict allKeys];

for (int i = 0; i < keys.count; i++) {
    NSDictionary *prodSingle = [productsDict objectForKey:[NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@",keys[i]]];
}
```

Now you have prodSingle, use this to get data of each product.

*Note: Untested, I'll provide a tested version if this doesn't work.*

**EDIT:**
As you said only `brands` key will remain constant and other will change dynamically,

you should do this :

So what you can do is create a NSDictionary with jsonData(response data) like this:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
```

create a dictionary of brands

```
NSDictionary *brandsDict = [jsonDictionary objectForKey:@"brands"];
```

Now get all the keys:

```
NSArray *keys= [brandsDict allKeys];
```

Now use each key you got in Array to fetch data accordingly.

Comment: ok brother  i ask dynamic change in my key value except "brand" .

Comment: i already use this method . if suppose i have 100 key value in the brand i choose to 100 method each time loop will generate 100 times.  app will be crashed

Comment: its dynamic key value .   constant key value is "brand" only

Comment: Answer edited. I can only provide you hints not full code as you can see.

Comment: i can explain clearly from my web data too.   there are four list view in web data .  if i select one list view then it show second list view according to first list view selection like as third and fourth list view according to previous selection

Comment: That will be more helpful.